# save the value of text box that has been selected from sql database

Tags: asp.net, database, session, button, textbox

i have this code in my button where it shows a value(credit request) from database to my text box.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CreditRequest FROM CreditRequests WHERE Username=@Username", scn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

            object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            if (value != null)
                txtCredit.Text = value.ToString();
        }
```

it works perfectly, but when i go to the other page and go back, the value is gone. Any tricks you can share on how to save my value in the text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in the text box will only be populated when the user clicks on `Button2` if you want the value to be populated when the page opens put the code in the `Page_Load` event